# Segmentation fault when different input is given

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, cimg

I do some image processing work in C++. For this i use CImg.h library which i feel is good for my work.

Here is small piece of code written by me which just reads an image and displays it.

```
#include "../CImg.h"
#include "iostream"

using namespace std;
using namespace cimg_library;

int main(int argc,char**argv)
{
     CImg<unsigned char> img(argv[1]);
     img.display();  
     return 0;  
}
```

When i give lena.pgm as input this code it displays the image. Where as if i give some other image, for example ddnl.pgm which i present in the same directory i get "Segmentation Fault".

When i ran the code using gdb i get the output as follows:

> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
>   0x009823a3 in strlen () from /lib/libc.so.6
>   Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.9-2.i686 libX11-1.1.4-5.fc10.i386 libXau-1.0.4-1.fc10.i386 libXdmcp-1.0.2-6.fc10.i386 libgcc-4.3.2-7.i386 libstdc++-4.3.2-7.i386 libxcb-1.1.91-5.fc10.i386

Can some one please tell me what the problem is? and how to solve it.

Thank you all

Comment: It's highly unlikely that this is related to your problem, but I think `#include <iostream>` is considered better than `#include "iostream"`

Comment: Is there any difference between the two images? Is one significantly larger, for example?

Comment: That CImg constructor that takes a filename can throw an exception (http://bit.ly/6hYyoi).  Also, you aren't checking argc so see if argv[1] is even defined.  Unsure if that's it, kind of guessing.  Did you try running this under a debugger like gdb?  If it catches an exception in gdb, type "backtrace" to see what happened.

Comment: Are you talking about a subsequent run of exactly the same program with only a different argument?  Also, what version of CImg are you using?

Comment: is `ddnl.pgm` a PGM image file or something else? From ux9i's link, it tries to determine the image type from the file's extension.

Comment: Reiterating what ux91 requested.  Please post the backtrace of the crash.  Run the program in gdb and once it crashes, type "backtrace" and post that.

Answer (score 1):

Segfault comes when you are trying to access memrory which you are not allowed to access.
So please check that out in the code.

Comment: Why the downvote?
It is correct. Not sure it's relevant but given the little info we've got he might be right.

Answer (score 1):

The code itself looks just fine. I can suggest some ways to go ahead with debugging -

1. Try removing the display() call. Does the problem still occur? (I'd assume it does).
2. Try finding out where in the CImg code is the strlen() that causes the segmentation fault (by using a debugger). This may give additional hints.
3. If it is in the PGM file processing, maybe the provided PGM file is invalid in some way, and the library doesn't do error detection - try opening it in some other viewer, and saving it again (as PGM). If the new one works, comparing the two may reveal something.

Once you have more information, more can be said.

**EDIT** -

Looking at the extra information you provided, and consulting the code itself, it appears that CImg is failing when trying to check what kind of file you are opening.

The relevant line of code is -

```
if (!cimg::strcmp(ftype,"pnm")) load_pnm(filename);
```

This is the first time 'ftype' is used, which brings me to the conclusion that it has an invalid value.

'ftype' is being given a value just a few lines above -

```
const char *const ftype = cimg::file_type(0,filename);
```

The file_type() function itself tries to guess what file to open based on its header, probably because opening it based on the extension - failed. There is only one sane way for it to return an invalid value, which would later cause strcmp() to fail - when it fails to identify the file as anything it is familiar with, it returns NULL (0, actually).

So, I reiterate my suggestion that you try to verify that this is indeed a valid file. I can't point you at any tools that are capable of opening/saving PGM files, but I'm guessing a simple Google search would help. Try to open the file and re-save it as PGM.

Comment: hi hexagon,

Thank you very much for the reply...i will try with these suggestions from you. I did not notice the comment section. For the next post on i will use it. Thanks.

Is there a way to check for valididty of PGM files ? I will google for it any way. If you know about it, please don't mind sharing.

One more thing, i had used imwrite function of Matlab to create these PGM files. I would trust the output of Matlab any time because many of my algorithms are poved correct using matlab.I think it shoud provide valid PGM file as output.

Comment: @sravan, I tend to agree with you - I would have trusted Matlab too. But as the PGM format is not very strict, there may be some incompatibility between the two. And no, I'm not away of a good way to check the validity of PGM files. You may want to step through the CImg code and see exactly how it fails - it may give you a hint as to what is wrong with the PGM file.

Comment: hi hexagon,Yesterday, i had downloaded few pgm files over Internet and tried the same program with these new images. Bingo!! It worked. Just to satisfy myself i had opened a JPG image using GIMP on linux and converted to PGM file. Even the newly created pgm file to worked with CImg. Hence, i came to conclusion that only the PGM images created using imwrite in Matlab was creating some problem for me. I don't whether the mistake imwrite of Matlab is generating the wrong PGM files or is it with CImg.As i have to proceed with my work i am using the pgm files which were downloaded. thanks hexagon

Answer (score 0):

Another "fun to track down" cause of segmentation faults is compilier mismatches between libraries - this is especially prevalent when using C++ libraries.

Things to check are:

1. Are you compiling with the same compiler as was used to compile the CImg library?
2. Are you using the same compiler flags?
3. Were there any defines that were set when compiling the library that you're not setting now?

Each of these has bitten me in subtle ways before.

Comment: In general these suggestions are sound. But specifically for the CImg library, it looks like it just lives in one large (very large...) header file. So separate compilation shouldn't be an issue - there is nothing to link to.

Comment: Indeed, scratch these ideas for CImg itself. But after looking at the CImg docs it forwards the reading/writing of certain formats to other libraries which could have these issues. However these libraries are predominantly C libs and thus less susceptible to this kind of issue.